# Invalid query: Invalid default value for 'created' in postfixadmin

Tags: mysql, postfix-mta

I encountered to Invalid " query: Invalid default value for 'created' " in postfixadmin problem and i just want to share my solution with you:
The MySQL "strict mode" is enabled, which doesn't allow the 0000-00-00 default value for date columns.

To work around this problem:
temporarily disable the strict mode in MySQL.
This method allows you to disable the strict mode on your MySQL server by running the following command.

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e "SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
```

Now, you can verify that the mode is set by running the following:

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"
```

and then:

```
systemctl reload postfixadmin
```

Comment: If you want to share such thing, ask yourself a question and then write your own answer

Comment: Also, did you read the tooltip for the tag `postfix-mta` by any chance

Answer (score 0):

This mysql query worked for me... after upgrading Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04:

```
> root@fast:/etc/mysql# mysql -u root  -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                                                                         |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
root@fast:/etc/mysql# mysql -uroot -e "set global sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';"
root@fast:/etc/mysql# mysql -u root  -e "SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;"
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @@GLOBAL.sql_mode                                                                        |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Drove me nuts trying to find the answer! I'm not sure if it will still work if I restart mysql.